# Make android phone as driver-free USB Webcam

Tags: root-access, usb, camera, webcam

I have a video call device which only works with driver-free usb webcams attached. Since I dont have a USB webcam at hand, so I wonder if I can make Android phone (rooted) emulated as a driver-free webcam via USB.

I knew some apk could work e.g. DroidCam, but they requires extra clients installed on Windows. I do not want IP webcam or wifi connection or http or VLC to view them, but plain old USB webcam.

Please note I am *not* asking for apps that can read videos from OTG usb webcams. It's the reverse, making Android output videos to USB.